# Options/best practice for evaluating the simulation rate in drake

Tags: drake

On Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) I used to use `drake_visualizer` for evaluating the simulation/realtime rate. With the dropped support for `drake_visualizer` in favor of `meldis` on jammy, is there an equivalent/similar functionality somewhere?

I can use `lcm-spy` to watch channels with known publish rates but that is a bit crude and noisy.

Answer (score 0):

Drake's `Meshcat` does have a nice realtime rate visualization which is available already if you use `MeshcatVisualizer`. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17661) to make it available from `meldis`, too.